# pandas, apply with args which are dataframe row entries

Tags: python, pandas, apply, args

I have a pandas dataframe 'df' with two columns 'A' and 'B', I have a function with two arguments

```
def myfunction(B, A):
    # do something here to get the result
    return result
```

and I would like to apply it row-by-row to df using the 'apply' function

```
df['C'] = df['B'].apply(myfunction, args=(df['A'],))
```

but I get the error

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

whats happening here, it seems it takes df['A'] as the whole series! not just the row entry from that series as required.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think you need:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6]})

print (df)
   A  B
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6

def myfunction(B, A):
    #some staff  
    result = B + A 
    # do something here to get the result
    return result

df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x: myfunction(x.B, x.A), axis=1)
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  1  4  5
1  2  5  7
2  3  6  9
```

Or:

```
def myfunction(x):

    result = x.B + x.A
    # do something here to get the result
    return result

df['C'] = df.apply(myfunction, axis=1)
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  1  4  5
1  2  5  7
2  3  6  9
```

Comment: why cant I use the 'args' argument for the apply function?

Comment: @RunnerBean you can pass arguments just fine.  `apply` accepts `kwargs` so you can pass arguments like this: `df['B'].apply(myfunction, A=df['A'])`  But in this case, it's a bad idea as you would be passing an entire series to a function applied at every row.

Answer (score 1):

I would add one more method, which could be useful when you need pass all columns to the function.

We consider that according to [`pandas.DataFrame.apply` docs:](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) *Objects passed to the function are Series objects*. So we convert `pd.Series` to `list`. Then unpack it using `*` operator, while our function call .

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6]})

print (df)
   A  B
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6

def myfunction(B, A):
    #some staff  
    result = B + A 
    # do something here to get the result
    return result

df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x: myfunction(*x.to_list()), axis=1)
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  1  4  5
1  2  5  7
2  3  6  9
```