# Load object from Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, oop, dataframe

I have an object **Gene**

```
class Gene:
    def __init__(self, id, nb_obj, nb_days):
        self.id=id
        self.nb_obj=nb_obj
        self.nb_days=nb_days
```

And I have a pandas dataframe **df**

```
   ID               nb_obj              nb_days
ECGYE                10259            62.965318
NLRTM                 8007            46.550562
```

How do I load each row of the dataframe to be a **Gene** object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandas, apply with args which are dataframe row entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39814416/pandas-apply-with-args-which-are-dataframe-row-entries)

Comment: Welcome to SO. I took the liberty to use code block formatting to refactor your question. You can format code blocks by indenting them by four spaces. Additionally I separated your parameters by a space (which is Python standard).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` that calls the constructor of `Gene`:

```
df.apply(lambda row: Gene(row['id'],row['nb_obj'],row['nb_days']), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
[Gene(df.ID.loc[i], df.nb_obj.loc[i], df.nb_days.loc[i]) for i in range(df.shape[0])]
```

Comment: Why don’t you use iterrows or itertuples method?